# Adjusting the relative space of panels in a facet-grid/facet_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

Is there a way to change the heights/lengths of the y-axis for individual facets in a `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`?

For example,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(economics_long[economics_long$variable %in% c("pop", "uempmed"),], aes(date, value)) +
    geom_line() +
    facet_grid(variable~., scales = "free_y") +
    theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

In the above plot, I would like the pop time series y-axis height/length to be, say, twice as large as the uempmed y-axis length (2:1), regardless of the fact the two time series have different y-axis scales.

Like what Kohske does here, in a much older version of ggplot2, which doesn't work in ggplot >=2.0.0:

https://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/25/adjusting-the-relative-space-of-a-facet-grid/

I know I can specify the argument `space = "free"` in `facet_grid`, but I don't think that argument can be used to set a 2:1 y-axis ratio?

I also don't want to use a "grid.arrange type" solution for lining up separately created ggplots (where I can make the 2 separate plots with different y-axis lengths), because I would ideally like to make use of Shiny's interactive ggplot2 features in this one single `facet_wrap` plot (e.g. an interactive shiny facet example with a brush is half way down the page here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selecting-rows-of-data.html).

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for your problem?  I am asking as I have the exact same question.  And what to do when you have 3 grids and you want them in a ratio (2, 1, 1).  It is quite easy to do with grid_extra and the heights parameter, but they don't align well vertically

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.  Maybe there is a way to it, particularly with the updates to ggplot2 over the past year or so but I'm not aware of it. 
 My guess is it probably still needs implementing in the ggplot2 source, which I'm not at all familiar with.

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple options.

With `facets`, you can use `facet_grid(..., space='free_y')` to have the height of each row adjusted to the length of the y-scale. In your data set, however, the bottom row is minimised to a single line (0-25 vs. 200,000 - 320,000).

When ggplot2 objects are plotted/printed, they are first converted to `gtable` objects. Saving your plot as `p`, we can call `ggplotGrob` to get the gtable object. This is a one-way procedure; once converted, you cannot convert the gtable back to a ggplot2 object!

```
(g <- ggplotGrob(p))
TableGrob (12 x 8) "layout": 18 grobs
    z         cells       name                                    grob
1   0 ( 1-12, 1- 8) background        rect[plot.background..rect.3766]
2   1 ( 6- 6, 4- 4)  panel-1-1               gTree[panel-1.gTree.3696]
3   1 ( 8- 8, 4- 4)  panel-1-2               gTree[panel-2.gTree.3711]
4   3 ( 5- 5, 4- 4)   axis-t-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
5   3 ( 9- 9, 4- 4)   axis-b-1    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.3725]
6   3 ( 6- 6, 3- 3)   axis-l-1    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.3733]
7   3 ( 8- 8, 3- 3)   axis-l-2    absoluteGrob[GRID.absoluteGrob.3741]
8   3 ( 6- 6, 6- 6)   axis-r-1                          zeroGrob[NULL]
9   3 ( 8- 8, 6- 6)   axis-r-2                          zeroGrob[NULL]
10  2 ( 6- 6, 5- 5)  strip-r-1                           gtable[strip]
11  2 ( 8- 8, 5- 5)  strip-r-2                           gtable[strip]
12  4 ( 4- 4, 4- 4)     xlab-t                          zeroGrob[NULL]
13  5 (10-10, 4- 4)     xlab-b titleGrob[axis.title.x..titleGrob.3714]
14  6 ( 6- 8, 2- 2)     ylab-l titleGrob[axis.title.y..titleGrob.3717]
15  7 ( 6- 8, 7- 7)     ylab-r                          zeroGrob[NULL]
16  8 ( 3- 3, 4- 4)   subtitle  zeroGrob[plot.subtitle..zeroGrob.3763]
17  9 ( 2- 2, 4- 4)      title     zeroGrob[plot.title..zeroGrob.3762]
18 10 (11-11, 4- 4)    caption   zeroGrob[plot.caption..zeroGrob.3764]
```

All the elements are set up in a grid-like layout. The height of each row in the layout is given by `g$heights`:

```
> g$heights
 [1] 5pt                 0cm                 0cm                 0cm                 0cm                 1null               5pt                 1null               0.396281911581569cm 1grobheight        
[11] 0cm                 5pt
```

Match the coordinate of 'panel-1-1' and 'panel-1-2' to these heights, and you'll find the 6th and 8th element are both `1null`. You can change them to any unit, cm, in, pt, ... The `1null` is simply what is left after the other elements, and divided among them. So we can change the 6th heigth to `2null` (note the use of double brackets):

```
> g$heights[[6]] <- unit(2, 'null')
> grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of this approach for making ggplots (I mentioned the `grid.arrange` type solutions in the question).  But I don't think this actually answer my specific question... I'd like to ultimately be able to adjust the y axis in facet_wrap, so I can use the interactive ggplot2 charts within Shiny...  See the brushed points example with the `facet_wrap` in the rstudio link I have in the question.  I'm not aware something like this is even possible using the `grob`s

Comment: It is unclear how brushedPoints works; my guess is that it does not recognise the individual points on the plot, but extrapolates the x- and y-coordinates covered, and returns any point from the given data.frame that falls within the region. Notice that the the function does not read the data.frame from the ggplot object, but must be given it explicitly; additionally you have to specify which facets are in use. You'll have a lot of work cut out for you if you try to combine these two functions in the manner you are trying; try instead to use two separate output plot gadgets.